# Problem while creating a Left function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a Left function in PostgreSQL as under

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LEFT(text, integer) RETURNS text 
    AS  'SELECT SUBSTR($1,$2);'
    LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

It got compiled fine. Now when I am invoking it as under

```
select LEFT(',a,b,c',2)
```

I am getting the output as `,a`

when the expected output is `a,b,c`

If I run `SELECT SUBSTR(',a,b,c' , 2)` it works as expected .

Please help me out in identifying the mistake

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEFT` function already exists in pg_catalog. So try a different function name or run

```
SELECT public.LEFT(',a,b,c' , 2)
```